# SQL like Clause (null and blank values)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

looking for the most effective way of using this condition to accept both NULL and BLANK values.

```
and region.Description like isnull(@Region, N'') + N'%'
```

This query works for NULLS however for EMTPY values it does not function. Any ideas to tweak this to perform both?

Comment: try ISNULL(NULLIF(@Region, ''), N)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, or which database you are using.  But depending on the answers to those questions, I'm guessing that COALESCE might do the trick for you better than ISNULL.

Comment: Thanks. SQL Server 2008.  if COALESCE is the better option - looking to understand how to factor that into the query. Do I simply replace the ISNULL

Comment: You would, but on reflection, I think COALESCE will provide the same results in this situation.  What is it that might be null or blank?  Region.Description or @Region?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it clearer to check for NULLs explicitly rather than doing any clever tricks with COALESCE() or ISNULL(). Then just also include blanks by checking the length of the string after trimming any whitespace.

```
(region.Description LIKE @Region + '%' OR @Region IS NULL OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Region)))=0)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. As I am passing parameter values from one SSRS Report to another this code will help me pass the blank value as the 'value' instead of null which was throwing off the drillthrough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
AND(  (isnull(@Region, N'')='' AND isnull(region.Description,'')='')
OR( isnull(@Region, N'')<>'' AND region.Description like @Region + N'%'))
```